# Why do psychologists tend to associate guilt with auditory admonition?

Tags: hearing

Can you please expound the sentence that I marked with red lines? The green underlie refers to Wolfram Eberhard's [1967 book *Guilt and Sin in Traditional China*](https://www.worldcat.org/title/guilt-and-sin-in-traditional-china/oclc/376374), page 12. But my library is closed because of COVID.

[image]

Axel Schuessler, *ABC Etymological Dictionary of Old Chinese* (2007), p 188.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book is [available free online in Open Library](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL5535599M/Guilt_and_sin_in_traditional_China.) and the Wolfram Eberhard reference seems to refer to

> Helen Lynd, *On Shame and the Search for Identity"* (New York, 1961), p. 207

[image: page clipping]

The 1961 copy is not on Open Library, but [there is a 1st edition copy from 1958](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL6245428M/On_shame_and_the_search_for_identity.).  **Please read from the bottom paragraph on page 207**.

Among others, the book points out that guilt involves

> exposure of a misdemeanour, with emphasis to whom exposed; exposure to something that should be hidden in a closet.

The book then compares it to Erik Erikson’s [8 life stages of man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erikson%27s_stages_of_psychosocial_development), originally put together in 1950 in his book *Childhood and Society*, which I covered in [an answer to another question about child development](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/17211/7604).